Implementing User-Based Device Filtering in ThingsBoard
Body
I am planning to filter devices based on the user in Thingsbaord . Imagine there is a main user; this user allows other users to see information about certain devices or not. I am planning the following:
I created a table that is appeared in each device detailed state , that shows the username, and next to it, a checkbox that allows the main user to grant this user access to a device ( to which in you are in detailed state). If it is true, the name of the device is written on the user's new telemetry or added because there could be more devices. After that, I plan to filter the table based on the user telemetry information (device names) so that some users can see information about only some devices ( which the main user allowed).
Challenges/Questions:
What is the best way to structure this data within ThingsBoard to facilitate efficient access control and filtering?
Are there any built-in ThingsBoard features that could simplify the management and filtering of device access based on user telemetry?

You can use Thingsboard's Entity Views
